# Notepad++ replace lines containing only spaces and/or tabs

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I replace all the lines in my code that contain only spaces and/or tabs with empty lines?

Example:

```
for(var l=0,leng=one.codes.length;l<leng;l++){
******
    var oneCode = one.codes[l];
    var temp = new Object();
******
    temp.code = oneCode.c;
******
    if(two >= 1000){
        var alex = "";
        var bob = 0;
    }
******
}
```

The * symbols are the spaces and tabs. I want them removed without changing the rest of the code format. I want this lines to remain blank but without containing any characters.

Comment: The answer you accepted `^\s+$` will remove subsequent/adjacent blank lines. Mavros, I got an impression you wanted to keep the line breaks, didn't you?

Comment: @MavrosGatos Did you look at the options available under the _Edit-->BlankOperations_ menu entry?  I'm guessing there is something there that will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Ctrl + H** to open the *Replace* tab
2. type `^\s+$` in the *Find what* text field
3. let the *Replace with* text field empty
4. select **Regular expression** in the *Search Mode* frame
5. Click the *Replace All* button (you may want to click *find* button few times before to check that the regex is correct)

Comment: This will remove subsequent/adjacent blank lines. Mavros, I got an impression you wanted to keep the line breaks, didn't you?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: you are right it actually replaces multiple blank line by only one...
so it should use \h instead of \s (I did not know \h before your answer, thanks ;) ) answer edited

Comment: Well, that just means my answer should get accepted. Now your answer is exact copy of mine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right on one point, our answers are now the same. But i think you modified yours as I modified mine.
I don't know who deserve the acceptance and I don't care, I am not running for points.
Feel free to contact MavrosGatos to ask him to fix this cruel injustice :)

Comment: What are you talking about? I modified the answer 7 minutes before you did. I only added screenshots 1 minute after you made your answer a duplicate of mine. See [my answer history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39161800/revisions). I leave it to the OP conscience to reconsider the accepted answer choice.

Comment: WiktorStribiżew: takling about the \R* of your initial answer... I don't want to argue, this dialog is useless. If this acceptance is so important for you, stop complaining and act: ask @MavrosGatos...

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
^\h+$
```

where:

- `^` - start of the line
- `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespace symbols
- `$` - end of line

**Note**: to also remove the line breaks, add a `\R*` - zero or more line breaks - at the end of the pattern.

[image]

VVVV

[image]

Comment: Nice answer but not exactly what I need. I don't want to remove the blank lines completely, just the whitespace symbols in them.

Comment: Then remove `\R*`. That will keep the line number intact, but will remove all horizontal whitespace in blank lines. Use `^\h+$`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
(?![^\s]).(\r?\n)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

This regex uses a negative lookahead, which will assert that at each point in the line the character which follows is not anything but whitespace (including space and tab).

The `\r?\n` end of the regex will match either `\r\n`, which is the Windows line ending, or just `\n`, which is the Unix line ending.  This is captured in `$1` and then used as the replacement, since you want to keep the line, while removing all whitespace.

[image]